# Water physics. Where to start?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics, game-physics

I've been searching all over Google for some advise or simply a way, to get started with water physics in any way or shape. I am making a game in Unity 3D that requires some cartoonish water physics that is smooth.

I know theres probably alot of plugins and libraries for this out there, but I just wanted to code it myself, to get more experience as a developer in general.

So basicly, my question is. Where should I start, If I want to make water physics/flow? Can you recommend any tutorials, articles etc?

Comment: I wonder why people downvoted. This is not a SO question (and it will be closed, most probably), but it's a legitimate question written in an understandable English.

Comment: Would that be 3D water or 2D water? (you said `cartoonish`, so that could kinda mean 2D).

Comment: Exactly. 2D, but I wouldn't mind a perspective on the 3D aswell.

Comment: Have you read [this](http://gamedev.tutsplus.com/tutorials/implementation/make-a-splash-with-2d-water-effects/) (2D)?

Comment: @Sam, No I haven't, that looks very interesting. I'll take a look at that!

Comment: if you are trying to reproduce sometyhing like the old mario games in water, you simply need to lower the level of the gravity.

Comment: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/95255-Fluvio-Multiphysics-and-Fluid-Dynamics

Comment: Intel has a nice [16 part series](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/fluid-simulation-for-video-games-part-1/) on fluid simulation.  You also might want to look at simulating water with particles.  I've found that to be an easier way of creating flow channels like rivers and such.

Comment: Well my goal with the water, is in the style of like Worms revolution. That kind of dynamic.

Comment: @KevinJensenPetersen: could you post a link to a video that has the types of effects that you're looking for (and if it's a long video, please indicate the time of interest)?

Comment: don't close yet... This isn't really a physics question, and in my view isn't off topic.  The OP isn't asking for details on the Navier-Stokes equation, but is asking, I think, how to make something look water-like in software.  This is a programming question, not a physics question, and at least I'm interested in programming approaches to this.

Comment: As am I @tom10 - but unfortunately this question does very little to define "water physics".

Comment: @Vikram: Yes, I agree.  I was hoping the OP would define more of what he wanted.  Instead, when he didn't get an easy answer he dropped it.  Fair enough, but since he has dropped it, it seems that the question should be deleted or closed.

Answer (score 1):

Most water physics models use implicit surfaces, driven by particles and springs.  It's basically the same as cloth but with different parameters.

For 2D, it's easier - [here's](https://web.archive.org/web/20160505235423/http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/graphics/x_water.htm) a good starting point.